# (online) Tool to calculate $E(\mathbb{Q})/2E(\mathbb{Q})$ for $E: y^2 = x(x^2 + 3x + 5)$

Tags: elliptic-curves, computer-algebra-systems

For some exercise I need to compute the generators of $E(\mathbb{Q})/2E(\mathbb{Q})$, where $E: y^2 = x(x^2 + 3x + 5)$

I did this by the approach from Cassels book 'Lectures on Elliptic Curves' and got the answer $< (0,0), (1,3) >$ which seems reasonable. A friend of mine did the same computation, but did not get $(1,3)$. Therefore we are looking for some (hopefully online) tool that computes this group. However, I know next to nothing of computer algebra systems, so we could use some help.

Comment: You can use [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/), which is also available online.

Comment: Which algorithm did you use? All I could find browsing Cassels' book is that there is no general algorithm for determining $E(\Bbb{Q})/2E(\Bbb{Q})$...

Comment: @A.P. sorry algorithm may not be the best choice of words. He does an example of this for a different curve, I applied the same method to this curve and got this answer. I will check out Sage, thank you!

Comment: @A.P. If you could post Sage as an anwser (and possibly some slight instruction on how to do this in Sage as I am new at it) I would gladly accept it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org), which is open-source and also available online. It has a vast library of functions related to elliptic curves, although I don't know if it can compute $E(\Bbb{Q})/2E(\Bbb{Q})$ directly.

It shouldn't be too difficult to pick up, especially if you know a bit of Python. You can start looking at the [tutorial](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/index.html) and at the section of the manual devoted to [elliptic curves](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plane_curves/index.html). In particular, be sure to check out how to [construct](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plane_curves/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/constructor.html) an elliptic curve and the [many functions](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plane_curves/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/ell_rational_field.html) specific for rational curves.

Without further ado, here's a little primer, which should be enough for your purposes (the lines starting with `sage:` are the input, minus the `sage:` part).

We can construct your elliptic curve with

> **sage:** x,y = var('x,y')
>   **sage:** E = EllipticCurve(y^2 == x*(x^2 + 3*x + 5))

Then we can inquire about its torsion subgroup

> **sage:** E.torsion_subgroup()
>   Torsion Subgroup isomorphic to Z/2 associated to the Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + 3*x^2 + 5*x over Rational Field
>
> **sage:** E.torsion_points()
>   [(0 : 0 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0)]

and about the rank and generators of the free part

> **sage:** E.rank()
>   1
>
> **sage:** E.gens()
>   [(1 : 3 : 1)]

I believe that this should be enough to conclude that indeed
$$
E(\Bbb{Q})/2E(\Bbb{Q}) = \langle (0,0), (1,3) \rangle
$$